# How to install and run gym box2d environment in google colab?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory, openai-gym

I have followed [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53352157/996366) to run a box2d enviroment without rendering it in google colab,

```
!apt-get install python-box2d
!pip install box2d-py
!pip install gym[Box_2D]
import gym
env = gym.make("BipedalWalker-v2")
```

but its showing this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-box2d is already the newest version (2.3.2~dfsg-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
Requirement already satisfied: box2d-py in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (2.3.8)
Requirement already satisfied: gym[Box_2D] in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.15.3)
  WARNING: gym 0.15.3 does not provide the extra 'box_2d'
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from gym[Box_2D]) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyglet<=1.3.2,>=1.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from gym[Box_2D]) (1.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from gym[Box_2D]) (1.17.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from gym[Box_2D]) (1.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle~=1.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from gym[Box_2D]) (1.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: future in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pyglet<=1.3.2,>=1.2.0->gym[Box_2D]) (0.16.0)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-10-62ca95674145> in <module>()
      3 get_ipython().system('pip install gym[Box_2D]')
      4 import gym
----> 5 env = gym.make("BipedalWalker-v2")

3 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/gym/envs/registration.py in load(name)
     16     mod_name, attr_name = name.split(":")
     17     mod = importlib.import_module(mod_name)
---> 18     fn = getattr(mod, attr_name)
     19     return fn
     20 

AttributeError: module 'gym.envs.box2d' has no attribute 'BipedalWalker'
```

I also tried to install this box2d from pip `pip install Box2D` but its not installing in colab. How do we install and run a box2d gym enviroment in google colag?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get it working with `!pip3 install box2d-py==2.3.8`.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Do make sure you restart the runtime in the Google Colab notebook before running these codes:

```
!pip install gymnasium
!pip install box2d
```

and then in another cell, run this

```
import gym
import gymnasium
env = gym.make("LunarLander-v2")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Please create a new Colab notebook, Click on File -> New notebook. On a new (fresh) Colab execute these:

```py
!pip3 install box2d-py
!pip3 install gym[Box_2D]
import gym
env = gym.make("BipedalWalker-v3")
```

The gym is installed by default in the new notebook however you have to install the box2d-py and gym[Box_2D]. Please close the current notebook if you have encountered the error. Simply use a new notebook (VERY IMPORTANT) and go on with above procedure of pip install. It will work!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Bellow worked for me.

```
!pip install swig
!pip install gymnasium
!pip install gym[box2d]
```